# Eloquent for Wordpress - Call to a member function on null for static methods on DB Facade

Tags: php, wordpress, eloquent

I've installed Eloquent in Wordpress for DB operations. My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "illuminate/database": "~5.0.0",
    "illuminate/events": "~5.0.0",
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "wp-content/themes/tkh/src/"
    }
  }
}
```

I've created the DB connection in eloquent.php:

```
<?php 
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
/*
 * Configure Eloquent (called Capsule when used alone)
 */

$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'tkh',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher(new \Illuminate\Container\Container));
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Now most things (save, delete, hasMany etc methods) seem to work fine. But calling static methods on the DB facade doesn't work.

A simplified example of calling the select method on the DB facade:

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
    if(isset($_POST['select']))
    {
        $schedule = DB::select('select 567567 from schedule where id = 77');
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>
```

When I click select I get this fatal error:

```
[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function select() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\wp-content\themes\tkh\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\index.php:0

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   2. require() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\index.php:17

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\wp-blog-header.php:19

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   4. include() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\wp-includes\template-loader.php:74

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   5. Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\wp-content\themes\tkh\page-schedules.php:6

[28-Sep-2017 11:04:03 UTC] PHP   6. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() C:\xampp\htdocs\tkh\wp-content\themes\tkh\page-schedules.php:6
```

It fails on the case 1 line in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade in the following function:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    switch (count($args))
    {
        case 0:
            return $instance->$method();

        case 1:
            return $instance->$method($args[0]);
```

When I debug that bit of code, I get these local vars:

```
Locals
$args array[1]
    $args[0] "select 567567 from schedule where id = 77"
    $instance null
$method "select"
    ::object [Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade]
    ::app null
        ::resolvedInstancearray [1]
        ::resolvedInstance['db'] null
```

So that $instance var is null and that causes the exception. I'm guessing that this is the db instance the method needs to execute on and that I need to create something extra in my eloquent.php file but hours of searching and research have not uncovered anything so I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on what this $instance variable is and how I can populate it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer to this here: https://github.com/illuminate/database

If you want to run Eloquent without Laravel, use the Capsule instead of the DB facade, like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$results = Capsule::select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
```